# Не могу подключить npm пакет в visual studio

Tags: javascript

Проблема такая - консоль полностью не распознает команды в которых есть слово "npm" на ютубе и курсах просто пишут "npm init" И он в миг работает!

Когда же я пишу тоже самое - слово npm подсвечивается желтым и вылазит такая прекрасная ошибочка

```
-PS C:\Users\Computer 1\Desktop\start> npm install

npm : Имя "npm" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария
или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания имени, а 
также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку. строка:1 знак:1

npm install
CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

пробовал уже через ctrl+p , пробовал как то с плагином.

Comment: Не ругайся. Почитай, вот здесь варианты расписаны https://question-it.com/questions/1760842/zapusk-komandy-npm-v-kode-visual-studio Возможно у тебя путь PATH не прописан..  В общем по этой ссылке найдешь инфу и всё у тебя получится, настойчивость и внимательность чуть ли не самое главное в программировании, команды лучше не руками набивать, а копировать.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install
```

Перевожу с машинного на человеческий: "через менеджер пакетов установить". А что установить??? Имя пакета где-то потерялось.

`init и install` - разные команды.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала проверьте установлен ли node.js
Если нет, то установите
Но если оно установлено, то попробуйте через Windows PowerShell(администратор) написать это
`Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser`
и потом ответить yes.
Чтоб найти Windows PowerShell(администратор) для тех кто не может найти, к иконке значка Пуск подводите мышь и нажимаете правую кнопку мыши и появится окно там можете выбрать Windows PowerShell(администратор).
Этот метод помог мне исправить такую ошибку