# Не получается запустить "npm init" через VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не получается запустить `git init` в VS Code, выдаёт сбой. Node.js я скачал.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. Может дело в плагинах или неправильной установке.

Comment: VS Code нуждается в пути установки Node.js в системных переменных PATH. Добавьте C:\Program Files\nodejs в PATH

Comment: Я добавил path, но команда `npm init` все равно не работает. Ввожу в powershell.

Comment: откройте окно powershell из панели задач windows и введите команды: node -v , npm -v. Они должны вам выдать номера версий, если работают, то всё должно работать и в VS Code. Если нет, то надо скачать и установить версию x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code нуждается в пути установки Node.js в системных переменных PATH. Добавьте C:\Program Files\nodejs в PATH.

[Подробный гайд с картинками](https://hangodesk.com/ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0-npm-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4)

Answer (score 0):

Сначала проверьте работают ли команды npm в терминале Если нет, то думаю следует переустановить node.js. Но если команды работают, то попробуйте через Windows PowerShell(администратор) написать это Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser и потом ответить yes Чтоб найти Windows PowerShell(администратор) для тех кто не может найти, к иконке значка Пуск подводите мышь и нажимаете правую кнопку мыши и появится окно там можете выбрать Windows PowerShell(администратор) Этот метод помог мне исправить такую ошибку

Comment: [идентичный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1470252/178576)

Answer (score 0):

Выдавало такую же ошибку в терминале VS Code. Попробовал ввести команды node -v и npm -v в powershell они у меня сработали. Потом перезагрузил компьютер. Запустил VS Code и у меня получилось в терминале выполнить команду npm init -y.